# add/remove multiple input fields and input rows dynamically PHP (Dynamic form In Dynamic Form)

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dynamic-forms, dynamicform

i am making a dynamic PHP form, i have successfully making dynamic form, how if i want to make form dynamic in dynamic fields, like in the table make a dynamic fields in dynamic Rows  ?

[this is my form view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b7IQ.png)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      var count = 0;
      $(document).on('click', '#addformdanger', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';

                  html += '<section>';
                  html += '<hr>';
                  html += 'my child form';

$('#form-body-danger').append(html); 
});
$(document).on('click', '#addprocess', function(){
        count++;
        var html = '';

                  html += '<section>';
                  html += '<hr>';
                  html += 'form child';

$('#form-body-process').append(html);
});


$(document).on('click', '.remove-danger',function(){
               $(this).closest('section').remove();
            });

$(document).on('click', '.remove-process',function(){
               $(this).closest('section').remove();
            });
```

[this My Output what i want,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLS78.png)

Comment: Make this more clear by showing us any image of output or code or elobrate the scenario.

Comment: i have update my question can you help me please, thanks you

Comment: By the output image you want, your question is related to HTML. Maybe you want do *rowspan* or *cellspan* within a html table, or maybe you want do it with CSS, but in both cases your question is excessively abstract; you are much more likely to get a helpful answer if you can provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Anyway, you should try writing firstly the final html code you want to be showed, and from there, you will find easy extract the html portions that will need being append by jQuery (or PHP)

Answer (score 0):

From what you've mentioned, what i understand is you're making a form in which user can add multiple inputs. And on clicking on submit, data should be sent back to server.

If this is the problem kindly [visit here](http://talkerscode.com/webtricks/create-dynamic-form-using-php-jquery-and-mysql.php).

You can also [refer](https://techstream.org/Web-Development/PHP/Dynamic-Form-Processing-with-PHP).

Both will helps you to create forms where user can add/remove more fields as per need.